# buidling a bandpass filter without using inbuilt functions

Tags: matlab, algorithms, dsp-core, bandpass, digital-filters

I got an assignment which require building a bandpass filter without using any inbuilt functions. I wanted to create a third order Butterworth bandpass filter

```
%for ecg
f1=5; %cuttoff low frequency to get rid of left over baseline wander
f2=15; %cuttoff frequency to discard high frequency noise
Wn=[f1 f2]*2/fs; % cut off based on fs
N = 3; % order of 3 less processing
[a,b] = butter(N,Wn); %bandpass filtering
f = filtfilt(a,b,ecg);
s1= f/ max( abs(f));
```

I wanted to get the coefficient without using `butter` function in MATLAB.

Comment: Could you format your question such that it becomes more legible? If I understand correctly you basically want to do what the function 'butter.m' does. Have you tried to find out what it does by looking at its code?

Comment: Butterworth filters are easy to design; the transfer functions of Butterworth filters of any order have an analytic expression. See the description [at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter), then use the [bilinear transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform) to map the analog prototype to a discrete-time filter.